Ajax y PHP con sleep en php
Tengo una aplicación web elaborada con ajax (Jquery) y php, sin embargo quiero implementar una funcionalidad y espero darme a entender.
Desde php tengo un sleep que imprime cada 2...5 segundos un texto, éste texto (el impreso) quiero llevarlo a ajax, sin embargo me encuento con lo siguiente, al momento de leer el primer echo obtengo una respuesta y ésta es procesada por ajax, quisiera obtener las multiples respuestas que se dan en el tiempo de unos 30 segundos en total.
Agradeciendo de antemano la colaboración y orientación que me puedan brindar.
Saludos

Por favor lee [ask] y como hacer un [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, también te invito a hacer el [tour]

Buenas, entiendo que expliques como lo estás haciendo, pero debes MOSTRAR como lo estás haciendo. Necesitamos ver tu php de ejemplo y el ajax con el que tratas de hacer lo que quieres hacer.

yo creo que si puedes implementar la funcionalidad...
